# Can I stop someone from transferring an ERC-721 token based on the smart contract I created?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I do not have much experience with Solidity programming. I want to create a smart contract for a new digital asset, say Cryptodoggies. I want to know if there is a way to prevent users from being able to resell/transfer their cryptodoggies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a variable (boolean I think would be more suitable) on your contract and use it in an access modifier for the transfer function so that the transfer function would require for this variable to be true. Then by making this variable false (by a function accessible only to you) you can stop users from transferring coins. Of course, this modifier would have to be used for every function that enables users to transfer tokens.

It would be something like that pausable ERC-20 from openzeppelin. You can find it [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Pausable.sol).